# Export database

Tags: linux, база-данных, oracle, unix

Нужно сделать экспорт/импорт данных из БД. Для этого нужна утилита exp. Где её найти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл ответ на английском stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23647408/how-to-export-database-schema-in-oracle-to-a-dump-file

Суть: команда **expdp** вместо **exp**.